# Random forests performed under expectation

Tags: c++, machine-learning, weka, random-forest, decision-tree

I am learning decision tree algorithm and implemented a random forest referring to the RF in Weka. I tested both my implementation and weka implementation (under default settings) with the same dataset. However the accuracy of mine was about 5% lower then the accuracy obtained by Weka version 3.8 (obtained by 'train-first1000.arff' training set and 'dev-first1000.arff' test set).

The arff format dataset I used was movie reviews from IMDb. For each instance, it contains a number of frequencies of top most frequent words and was labeled with either 'P' (for positive) or 'N' (for negative).

For comparison, I used default settings in Weka random forests (100 trees, log() + 1 features considered during split, no baggings and etc)

Here is the Weka results with default settings and my results with same settings (100 trees, 10 random features considered during split):

[image: Weka results and my results]

Firstly I thought there're bugs in my data importers. Then I checked my importers and compared with python arff importers and found that they were performing correctly.

Then I checked the source code of weka RF:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev/3.7.5/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomForest.java

and compared with mine carefully more than one times to make sure the implementations were the same. Yet I was not able to find a reason why there was still a 5% difference.

Here is the link to my implementation:

https://github.com/YSZhuoyang/Parallelized-Random-Forests/tree/randomforests

More specifically, the main part of training algorithm can be found in "TreeBuilder.cpp" and "TreeBuilder.h".

**Updated:**

I tested 10 features data and 50 features data separately, the results obtained by my implementation were all lower than weka implementation.

10 Features (100 trees, 4 features to consider during split):
[image: 10 features, 100 trees]

50 Features (100 trees, 6 features to consider during split):
[image: 50 features, 100 trees]

To organize the results a bit and make it more persuasive in terms of the variations due to randomization, I grouped them into the following table (50 features in total, 6 random features considered during split, both random seeds were set to 1):

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| num total features | num trees | weka result | my result |
|         50         |     1     |    55.61    |   52.34   |
|         50         |     5     |    59.08    |   54.35   |
|         50         |     10    |    60.07    |   55.43   |
|         50         |     20    |    62.54    |   57.20   |
|         50         |     50    |    64.14    |   59.56   |
|         50         |    100    |    65.28    |   61.09   |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

which showed that it was not due to randomizations.

**Solved:**

I used diabetes dataset provided by weka which has 8 features only (followed the suggestion given by @alexeykuzmin0), and tested it with random tree on weka, considering all features during split. Then I visualized the tree and compared with my tree, and found that the split point selected on root node was different from mine, which seemed that my calculation of information gain was wrong. Finally I figured out that there was a type error that casted a double type value into an int type, which let to the inaccurate results.

A piece of code:

```
// Compute entropy of children
for (const vector<unsigned int>& group : groups)
{
    double entropyChild = ComputeEntropy( group );

    // Before being corrected
    // unsigned int numChildren = group.size();
    // infoGain -= numChildren / numInstances * entropyChild;

    // Corrected
    double numChildren = group.size();
    infoGain -= numChildren / (double) numInstances * entropyChild;

}
```

Here is an updated version of comparison of mine and weka:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| num total features | num trees | weka result | my result |
|         50         |     1     |    55.61    |   55.34   |
|         50         |     5     |    59.08    |   58.73   |
|         50         |     10    |    60.07    |   60.86   |
|         50         |     20    |    62.54    |   62.97   |
|         50         |     50    |    64.14    |   64.68   |
|         50         |    100    |    65.28    |   65.35   |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks for all answers and help.

Comment: This is way too much reading for the average gal/guy here. If you want any chance in help post actual code here, only the smallest part of what you did that you now think is causing the difference.

Comment: @kabanus
Yes I understand however I am not able to narrow down further, since I am not sure where the problem is, sorry about that. The only thing I am able to point out is the class file "TreeBuilder.cpp" that might be the one where problem occured.

Comment: Try creating the smallest dataset with different results - probably, if you have some bug, it will appear or just a tiny dataset of 1-3 objects, which is much simpler to debug

Comment: The question, however painfull it might be to your efforts, ought become a [**V**erifiable ] MCVE-problem. Might have already re-read the **advice on how to best ask Questions on StackOverflow** >>> http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so try to isolate a re-testable case, post it with both implementation-source and DataSET ( and perhaps with Weka pre-computed results ) to chase down the root-cause. Still a pretty high-level set of troubles ( let the randomisation differences be just the one to mention )

Answer (score 1):

Two implementations of the (almost) same learning algorithm will be principally different in many aspects. That introduces a principal difference the same DataSET will receive slightly different results from otherwise similar high-level machine-learning process.

Event if the implementation is exactly the same, the results are not guaranteed to be identical. The best case to show this is right the Random Forest class of machine-learning learners:

### Random Forests are Breimann's Forests of highly Randomised Trees

Notice the word **Randomised**.

As noted in the comment above, even if none of other implementations' differences may be of kind readers interest, the very nature of the Random Forest requires randomisation -- as a re-used tool -- to take place in the processing.

Rigorous research requires repeatable experiments to be used and thus Random Forest learners typically allow to provide an explicitly provided value of a **`seed`** value for the underlying RNG ( random number generator ).

Testing the same **`RandomForest`** `.fit()` method on the same **`DataSET`**, but with different **`seed`** value provided yields a certain amount of variance in the resulting (im)-precision achieved on the otherwise principally identical process repetitions. Providing the same `seed` value ought provide the same results ( if and only if, in case, no other host-co-located process damages the interim stateful-states of the RNG-factory used inside the Random Forest generation phase ).

[image]

Good news is, that this amount of the **principal variance** reduces from some >10% down, as the ensemble grows ( the lower the number of trees, the lower the principal RNG-introduced variance ).

### So 4% ~ 6% are quite within the reach of this sort of phenomena for RF.

[image]

**Z-axis** shows the **increasing predictive performance** of the Random Forest ensemble method **+ decreasing amount of principal variance** ( introduced by the different `RNG( seed )` ) superimposed on the predictions.

**X-axis** ( running to the right ) carries `N_trees`

**Y-axis** ( running to the left ) carries `seed`-ordinal number ~ 100 different explicit `seed` values ( started from `aBASE, aBASE+1, +2, +3, ..., +99` )

---

### Epilogue

Given the OP, you can re-test your own implementation for RNG-`seed` dependence by re-running your RF-learner implementation on the same `DataSET` to receive a quantitative assessment of this phenomenon on your `[ Your-Learner, DataSET, ( Your-RNG, seed ) ]` (now)-deterministic system.

If you can perform the same test on `[ Weka-Learner, DataSET, ( Weka-RNG, seed ) ]` complex, the sharper view on this principal landscape you get.

Comment: Thanks @user3666197
The answer is helpful. However my results showed that the difference of 2 implementations (or say the principal variance) does not decrease with the growth of the ensemble (I tested with 10, 20, 50, 100 trees), and mine was always lower which seems pretty unusual.

Comment: Would you mind, Oscar, posting a copy of MCVE-DataSET + list of HyperParameterVECTOR setups, used for Weka RF-process and for your-implementation RF-process and the observed quantitative results on the commented behaviour?

Comment: I have organized the results obtained into a table which might it easier to see the difference.